# Why scipy.io.wavfile.read does not return a tuple?

Tags: python, wav, scipy

I am trying to read a *.wav file using scipy. I do the following:

```
import scipy
x = scipy.io.wavfile.read('/usr/share/sounds/purple/receive.wav')
```

As a result of this code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = scipy.io.wavfile.read('/usr/share/sounds/purple/receive.wav')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'io'
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error says, scipy module does not have 'io'.

`io.wavfile` is a submodule, you need to `from scipy.io import wavfile` and then do `wavfile.read("/usr/share/sounds/purple/receive.wav")`

This gives me an error with the file you are using as an example, however...

Comment: Why scipy does not have io? Why people write scipy.io if scipy does not have io?

Comment: The behaviour is a bit odd and unclear to me as well. Hopefully someone more enlightened will explain why this is so...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped to fix the problem. But a new problem appear: "cannot import name NumpyTest". I have already asked a new question about that.

Comment: ...and I have answered that too :)